# Amazon cloudfront not storing cache and always gets x-cache: Miss from cloudfront in browser in webpage header

Tags: caching, amazon-cloudfront, aws-amplify

0
I have NextJS ISR Application deployed on AWS Amplify. I set cache control policy in amplify.yml as customHeaders: - pattern: '/job/*' headers: - key: 'Cache-Control' value: 'public, max-age=14400, s-maxage=14400, stale-while-revalidate=7200'

and also in next.config.js as async headers() { return [ { source: "/job/:job_search", headers: [ { key: "Cache-Control", value: "public, max-age=14400, s-maxage=14400, stale-while-revalidate=7200", }, ], }, ]; },

also I set Behaviors in cloudfront distribution to store cache, but even though i am not able to get cache from cloudfront for my static pages. when i hit static page from postman i get page from cloudfront cache and get in header as X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront and also response in fast, But when i hit page from browser i dont get page form cache and also pages take time to load and in header i get X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront.

I am not getting how should i set settings so that my static pages will serve from cache ?

static page need to come from cloudfront cache

Comment: What are the headers you get on that page? what is the behavior you defined?